# Sum of divergent infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

A series goes 1 + 1/2 + 2/3 + 3/4 + 4/5....

Is there a possible summation equation for this series?

Since it gets smaller only after the first term and never anywhere else.

Comment: Have you tried calculating some partial sums and finding a pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the general term is larger than $\frac12$, the sum is larger than $\frac12\times$ the number of terms and hence it diverges.

The partial sum is related to the [Harmonic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

$$1 + \frac12 + \frac23 + \frac34 + \frac45...=1+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k-1}k=1+\sum_{k=1}^n(1-\frac1k)=1+n-H_n.$$

The Harmonic numbers only grow as the logarithm of $n$.

Comment: only grow as the logarithm of n...grows?

Answer (score 1):

$$1+\sum_1^\infty\bigg(1-\frac1n\bigg)=1+\sum_1^\infty1-\sum_1^\infty\frac1n\equiv1+\zeta(0)-\zeta(1)\equiv\frac12-\gamma.$$ $\quad$ Another option would be $\dfrac12-\ln2$, since both values appear in various formulas as regularized values for $\zeta(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

In the standard definition of a sum, that is,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^Na_n,$$

The sum you wrote clearly diverges, since

$$\sum_{n=1}^Na_n > \sum_{n=1}^N\frac12 = \frac{N}{2}.$$

This means that the generalized limit is $\infty$, but a limit does not exist.