# Series converges or diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Does the series converge?

$$ 1+\frac 1 {3^2}-\frac12 +\frac1 {5^2} + \frac 1{7^2} - \frac14 \cdots + \frac1{(4n+1)^2} + \frac1{(4n+3)^2} - \frac 1{2n+2}+\cdots$$

I can see that the series does not converge absolutely by comparison of $\sum1/(2n+2)$ with $\sum 1/n$ but this does not imply anything about its conditional convergence.

Also, if it converges conditionally, then its rearrangements will converge to any real number including $\infty$ ($\pm\infty$).

Please suggest a test using comparison/root test/ratio test since I am following Rudin alone .

Answer (score 2):

It cannot converge, since $\sum (\frac{1}{(4n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(4n+3)^2})$ converges but $\sum \frac{1}{2n+2}$ diverges, the sum of the two series is doomed to diverge.

Comment: Yeah but that is true for absolute convergence. What about conditional convergence?

Comment: It's true for conditional convergence. If $\sum a_n$ diverges and $\sum b_n$ converges, then $\sum a_n+b_n$ diverges (conditionally).

Comment: It just doesn't matter, what I say is still true. The sum of two divergent series can converge, but divergent+convergent=divergent.

Comment: What you have written is a rearrangement of the original series. It cannot be guaranteed that if a rearrangement diverges, other rearrangements also diverge. What we can be sure about is that if a series converges absolutely then all its rearrangements converge to the same value, but it is not the case with this series, since the series diverges absolutely.

Comment: No it's not a rearrangement. I only wrote it as the sum of two series. Just consider the partial sums as two sequences of which the limit of the sum is your serie. Well it's clear that if $(a_n)_n$ diverges and $(b_n)_n$ converges then $(a_n+b_n)_n$ diverges.

Comment: But you have clubbed the positive terms together and the negative terms together, so it is a rearrangement, don't you think?

Comment: Could you please explain in detail why it is not a rearrangement?

Comment: Please stop thinking in terms of series or rearrangements. Juste think in terms of the sequences $a_n= \sum_{k=0}^n (\frac{1}{(4k+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(4k+3)^2})$, $b_n=-\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{2n+2}$. Then $(c_n)_n$ defined by $c_n=a_n+b_n$ is divergent. Because $a_n$ is convergent and $b_n$ is divergent. That's just it. No need to be confused with rearrangement, it's only a simple sequence issue.

Comment: Now I am very confused about rearrangements though . Can you please explain when can we write the following? $\sum [1/(4n+1)^2+ 1/(4n+3)^2 + 1/(2n+2)]$ = $\sum [1/(4n+1)^2+ 1/(4n+3)^2]$ + $\sum 1/(2n+2)$ . Essentially you have written it like this. Can you please explain why can we not call it as rearrangement?

Comment: You're confused because rearrangements are meaningless when you manipulate series with terms of constant signs. 
If $(a_n)$ is a sequence that never changes of sign, then rearranging the terms will never change the limit. That is especially true for series of positive terms, and here since you can seperate the converging part of the diverging part there is no doubt about the divergence of the series.
That is different from cases like $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$, where the terms change signs each time. This can be rearranged to make it converge to any real number x, because of the change of sign.

Comment: I've written something here about rearrangements that can change the limit: 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/982230/is-there-any-method-to-get-a-finite-sum-for-1-frac12-frac13-frac1/982271#982271
if you're interested

Answer (score 1):

For conditional convergence (but not absolute convergence) you must have divergence of both the series of positive terms and the series of negative terms.  As Pierre pointed out: in this case you have convergence of one but not of the other.

Comment: Thank you. I hope that some support might be able to make Martin trust what I say.

Comment: @Pierre: I assume you are correct, but I am very confused at this point with rearrangements

Comment: @GEdgar: Did you mean convergence in your comment? "For conditional convergence (but not absolute convergence) you must have divergence of both"

Answer (score 0):

In
$\frac1{(4n+1)^2} + \frac1{(4n+3)^2} - \frac 1{2n+2}$,
the last term swamps the other terms,
since its sum diverges
while the sum of the others converges.

However,
if the terms are
$\frac1{(4n+1)^2} + \frac1{(4n+3)^2} - \frac 2{(4n+2)^2}$,
things get trickier.

$\begin{array}\\
d(n)
&=\frac1{(4n+1)^2} + \frac1{(4n+3)^2} - \frac 2{(4n+2)^2}\\
&=\frac{(4n+3)^2(4n+2)^2+(4n+2)^2(4n+1)^2-2(4n+3)^2(4n+1)^2}{(4n+1)^2(4n+2)^2(4n+3)^2}\\
&=\frac{(4n+3)^2(4n+2)^2-(4n+3)^2(4n+1)^2+(4n+2)^2(4n+1)^2-(4n+3)^2(4n+1)^2}{(4n+1)^2(4n+2)^2(4n+3)^2}\\
&=\frac{((4n+3)(4n+2)-(4n+3)(4n+1))((4n+3)(4n+2)^2+(4n+3)(4n+1))+((4n+2)(4n+1)-(4n+3)(4n+1))((4n+2)(4n+1)-(4n+3)(4n+1))}{(4n+1)^2(4n+2)^2(4n+3)^2}\\
&=\frac{((16n^2+20n+6)-(16n^2+16n+3))((16n^2+20n+6)+(16n^2+16n+3))+((16n^2+12n+2)-(16n^2+16n+3))(16n^2+12n+2)+(16n^2+16n+3))}{(4n+1)^2(4n+2)^2(4n+3)^2}\\
&=\frac{(4n+3)(32n^2+36n+9)+((-4n-1)(32n^2+28n+5))}{(4n+1)^2(4n+2)^2(4n+3)^2}\\
\end{array}
$

Looking at the numerator,

$\begin{array}\\
(4n+3)(32n^2+36n+9)-((4n+1)(32n^2+28n+5))
&=(128n^3+(32\cdot 3 + 4\cdot 36)n^2+O(n))
-(128n^3+(32+4\cdot 28)n^2+O(n))\\
&=(96 + 144-32-112)n^2+O(n))\\
&=96n^2+O(n)\\
\end{array}
$

so
$d(n)
=
\frac{96n^2+O(n)}{(4n+1)^2(4n+2)^2(4n+3)^2}
$

and
the sum of these converges.

P.S.
If I haven't made any algebra errors in this,
I will be surprised,
but the final conclusion
about the convergence
of the modified sum
should be correct.